# CSS content area 100% height

Tags: css, layout

I am trying to stretch the content area of the page to 100%. I have got a fixed header (50px height) and a sticky footer (95px height) and anything in between should use 100% height...However I can't get this to work. Here is my CSS

```
<div id="wrap">
    <!-- fixed top navigation -->
    <div id="main">
        <!-- main content -->
    </div>
</div>
<footer>
    <!-- footer -->
</footer>
```

The CSS is like this

```
html, body {
height: 100%; /* needed for container min-height */
}

#wrap {min-height: 100%;}

#main {
  position:relative; /* needed for footer positioning*/
  overflow:auto;
  padding-bottom: 95px; /* must be same height as the footer */
  padding-top:50px;
  min-height:100%;
}  

footer {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -95px; /* negative value of footer height */
  height: 95px;
  background-color:#ebebeb;
}

body {margin:0px;padding:0px;}
```

Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

if you've putted the footer relative ("sticky") meaning you want you website to scroll down with the content.

so you need do create another div ("block") -> in the HTML position the div between header and footer, 
and give it a width of 100% and a height of auto; (meaning: the div will fill up verticaly with the amount of content putted in it.

Comment: and without the overflow, overflow is for treating content inside the div not in relation for positioning the div in a page flow.

Comment: and for you're own sake, give this tutorial a look. it will really help you understand positioning better. http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/

Comment: yes but if the content is not enough to fill up the space, I want it to stretch to the footer. ie page backgrounds etc should stretch to the footer even though the content may not....I hope I made myself clear.

Comment: try turning your footer and header to liquid sizing (%) and then:  100% of the body - footer height - header height = content height

Answer (score 0):

you can make the footer like

```
footer{
        position: absolute;
        border: 3px solid #eee;
        height: 30px;
        top: auto;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

i have tried before a lot
try use javascript to set height 100%

or try to use frameset

**UPDATE**

this article for using css
http://www.dave-woods.co.uk/index.php/100-height-layout-using-css/
but i am sure 90% that it may have a problems with different browsers but try it.

and this article for using jQuery
http://nicholasbarger.com/2011/08/04/jquery-makes-100-height-so-much-easier/

and this for using frameset
http://www.echoecho.com/htmlframes08.htm
and 
http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_frames.asp

Finally you will choose what is useful for your project
Good Luck

My Regards

Answer (score 0):

The best and simple way is

```
html,body{
 height:100%;
}
#wrap {
 height: calc(100%-50px-95px); 
}
.footer {
 //your code here
 height: 95px;
}
```